# Android XML layout - centered TextView

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, centering

I have created a very simple layout. XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_download_data_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/download_initial_data" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The graphic result of this layout looks like this (from Eclipse):

[image]

Can you explain me, please, why the text in `TextView` is not centered horizontally? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use `android:layout_gravity=center_horizontally` rather center

Comment: @Saqib: you mean `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: Change android:layout_width="match_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" in TextView width

Comment: your layout worked for me and the textview was centered. but i tried it with hardcoded text. the eclipse graphical layout is a bit buggy sometimes. try running on a device and see if the textview is still not centered., also try with a hard coded text in textview:
android:text="Downloading data. please wait..."

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: This works fine, but only if `TextView` has only one row. If it has two or more rows, the text is not centered in `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_download_data_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="download_initial_data" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dear Amsheer the difference between your answer and Ali Bagheri Shakib is that you don't use @string tag to get the text(that is wrong) second and this is incorrect is that you use like Ali Bagheri Shakib fill_parrent that should be replace with match_parrent